# Suggestions for Rigid Attribute Relationships

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008

I have a rigid relationship defined between two attributes in a dimension. This is a business case, and we expect that the "parent" attribute will never change. However, we are seeing an intermittent circumstance where, during a ProcessUpdate of the dimension, the query for the parent attribute is executed first, and before query for the the child attribute is executed, a record is inserted into the underlying database. Thus, when the child attribute query is executed, it reads data that wasn't present when the first attribute was processed, and thus the parent attribute is presumably assigned the unknown member. During the next ProcessUpdate of that dimension, since the parent attribute now picks up the new data and sees that the parent attribute is no longer the "unknown" member but another valid member, an error is thrown proclaiming that the rigid relationship was violated.

What actions can be taken here?

1. Remove the rigid relationship -- but if rigid relationships are supposed to be defined by business cases, and we have a valid business case, is this just a design flaw in SSAS?
2. Arrange the order in which the attributes are processed -- If the child attribute was processed before the parent attribute, then we wouldn't be encountering this issue. Is arranging processing of attributes even possible in SSAS?
3. Do a full process on the dimension -- We have other dimensions with rigid relationships, should we set them all to ProcessFull? If so, then, to keep rigid relationships, why even have the other processing options?
4. Are there other options to consider, like maybe changing the error configuration, or something?

Please let me know what you think would be the best approach.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going with option #2 (arrange the order of process) using the 'sequential (transaction mode) processing option - [here's more detail](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174774.aspx).  You might also want to run the 'impact analysis' to verify object dependencies - [steps to implement here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337509.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Lynn, I have investigated the sequential processing option, but I'm more looking for specifying the order of processing attributes within a single dimension. I couldn't find any documentation on that. Thanks again.